# console.log native code error in google chrome and android browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im using following function to display data after user click on sign up button.This works perfectly fine on Mozilla firefox but gives native code error on Google chrome and Android browser where im wrong ?

```
    function postdata(){
var chkfrm = checkdata();
if(chkfrm == 0){
    var url = 'http://domain.com/index.php/Signup/signin';    
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#formI").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       beforeSend:function(){
     $("#signupdiv").html('<img src="http://domain.com/images/signuploading.gif" />');
       },
       success:function(data)
       {
          $("#signupdiv").html(data);
       },
       error:function () {
            alert(console.log);      
       }
    });
    }
    else {
$("#msgjava").html('<p>We need a little bit information from you.Please fill it.</p>');
    return false;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` is a function, you should either use `alert(something)` or `console.log(something)`

```
error:function (data) {
    alert(data); // or console.log(data)      
}
```

Comment: what should i alert here for this code im not good at javascript

Comment: returned me [object Object]

Comment: @SPSingh That means it's an object, so you should use console.log and read the console. Only use alert for strings, numbers and such